# InDesign GREP code for find words between a full stop (.) and a colon (:)

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

What is the GREP code for finding all words between a full stop (.) and a colon (:) and then selecting those words and the colon (but not the fullstop)? For example: '. *Tone:*' or '. *Final result:*') in a body of copy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a positive look-behind

```
(?<= ... )
```

And a positive look-ahead

```
(?= ... )
```

`\.` Dots need to be backslashed. 
`/s` for the space. 
`\w` for letters and numbers. 
`?` for optional characters. 
And `*` to catch multiples.

```
(?<=\.\s?)\w*(?=:)
```

I recommend [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to help create and lookup regex syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If the period `.` might also be preceded by a word, as per your example, "`somthing. Tone:`" you might try this:

```
(?<=[a-z.]\s)[\w\s]+:
```

"`Tone:`" will be selected if your string looks like "`. Tone:`"; and
"`some other thing Tone:`"will be selected if your string is "`something. some other thing Tone:`"